# Exception Settings Missing in VS for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I just switched from a PC to a Mac for web development.  We use ASP.NET Core, and we develop the backend using Visual Studio.

I'm just trying to find the Exception Settings window in VS for Mac.  In PC it's in Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, but this is missing in VS for Mac.

Unfortunately, all the MS documentation (for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022) says that that is where the window is found, but it's not there.

Here is a screenshot so you know I'm not crazy:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac does not have an Exception Settings window.

Instead Visual Studio for Mac has a Breakpoint dialog where you can create a breakpoint for an exception. To open this dialog select Debug - New Breakpoint - New Exception Breakpoint.

[image: Debug - New Breakpoint - New Exception Breakpoint menu]

The dialog that opens allows you to specify the exception that the breakpoint should be associated with.

[image: New exception breakpoint dialog]